# Angular 2 Hide child componenets on click

Tags: angular

I want to hide whole component when I click on the certain radio button.
Child node selectors are: app-node-details-full, and app-node-tree-diagram. Here is my code of parent template:

```
<div class="displaySwitch">
  <input (click)="fullview.hidden = !fullview.hidden" checked type="radio" name="displayType" value="diagram"> Full View
  <input (click)="diagram.hidden = !diagram.hidden" type="radio" name="displayType" value="fullview"> Diagram
</div>
```

These are the radio buttons with (click) attached to them

Now in other div I have my child components:

```
  <div class="nodeDetails" [ngStyle]="nodeDetailsStyle">
    <app-node-details-full #fullview</app-node-details-full>
    <app-node-tree-diagram #diagram></app-node-tree-diagram>
  </div>
```

Both divs are wrapped in one main, if that means something to you. What am I doing wrong? Every time I click on radio button I get exception

> o.diagram is undefined

or

> o.fullview is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot set variables from inside the template

You have the following line :

```
(click)="fullview.hidden = !fullview.hidden"
```

You will need to extract this into a method

```
hide(){
    fullview.hidden = !fullview.hidden
}
```

And then trigger this method on click:

```
(click)="hide()"
```

### edit:

I notice that you are actually trying to set a template variable.

Template Variables only exist in the template, you cannot access them through JS (because they are compiled out into HTML) in order to access them you will need to use [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

Although I wouldn't recommend that approach.

*Instead* - I would control the visibility with component variables and `ngIf`

Answer (score -1):

```
*ngIf="myVar"
```

or

```
[hidden]="!myVar"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting `undefined` because, I think, you have your variables `#fullview` and `#diagram` defined *after* your radio buttons that are trying to use the variables.  I think you might be better off using a private variable and capturing the value of the selected radio button.  Then use `*ngIf` off of that.

Example:

```
checkboxValue: string;

<div class="displaySwitch">
  <input checked type="radio" name="displayType" [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue" value="fullView"> Full View
  <input type="radio" name="displayType" [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue" value="diagram"> Diagram
</div>

<div class="nodeDetails" [ngStyle]="nodeDetailsStyle">
  <app-node-details-full *ngIf="checkboxValue == 'fullView'"</app-node-details-full>
  <app-node-tree-diagram *ngIf="checkboxValue == 'diagram"></app-node-tree-diagram>
</div>
```